# Trigger slert automatically after set Date.Parse

Tags: javascript

what would be the proper way to automatically trigger `cuteAlert` after `time` is met? Does an `onLoad` with a `wait`have to be added?

```
const time = Date.parse('10 June 2021 10:00:00+4000') - Date.now();
if (time > 0) {
   setInterval(()=>{

var info1 = document.getElementById("info1");
info1.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  cuteAlert({
      type: "info",
      brand: "TestVer1",
      title: "Test Alert",
      message: "Message Test...",
      buttonText: "Okay"
  })
})

}, time )
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `info1.addEventListener` wrapper…? You’re binding a click listener after some amount of time. Not sure that makes sense.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks I will give that a try.

Comment: @SebastianSimon unfortunately removing the Eventlistener did not worker

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you are calculating `time` as the amount of time between now and the time you want to show the alert. In that case, you want `setTimeout` not `setInterval`. `setInterval` sets a _repeating_ timer, firing every X milliseconds. [Here's an article about the two](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval).